# Flask - saved zip is corruped

Tags: python, api, flask, post, zip

I send a zip to Flask using

```
import requests

file = open("path_to_zip...\\data.zip")
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', files={"archive": ("data.zip", file)})
```

And the main.py is as follows

```
import os
import flask
from flask_restful import Api
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def check_packet():
    file = flask.request.files['archive']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), buffer_size=16384)
    file.close()
  
    return flask.Response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

where I try to save the zip file to current working directory, os.getcwd(). The zip-file does get saved, but is invalid and I cannot open it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with the file? Is it truncated or encoded in some way?

Comment: The originating file is a simple folder with a json file inside, right-clicked and zipped. The result, the new zip file, is simply that I cannot open it/unzip it.

Comment: That can mean anything. Please find out what exactly is wrong with the file!

Comment: Check [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) for an example. Try opening the file in binary mode, and remove the tuple from your code.